# Matching pdf with the Inverted Gamma Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

So the Inverted Gamma probability density function is: $\displaystyle{f(x; \alpha, \beta) = \frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)} x^{-\alpha - 1}\exp\left(-\frac{\beta}{x}\right)}$

The equation I'm dealing with is:

$\displaystyle{f(\sigma; ?, ?) = \frac{2}{\Gamma\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)}\left(\frac{v\hat{\sigma}^2}{2}\right)^{\frac{v}{2}} \frac{1}{\sigma^{v+1}}\exp\left[\frac{-v\hat{\sigma}^2}{2\sigma^2}\right]}$

with parameters $\displaystyle{v}$ and $\displaystyle{\hat{\sigma}}$

Clearly $\displaystyle{\alpha = \frac{v}{2}}$, but what's $\displaystyle{\beta}$?

Comment: OP writes: `So the Inverted Gamma probability density function is ... blah`. ......... There are many different competing names and functional forms for distributions. The thing above that you refer to as an Inverted Gamma ... I would call an Inverse Gamma, the latter describing the pdf of $1/X$, when $X$~Gamma$(a,b)$, where $a$ = your $\alpha$, and $b$ = 1/(your $\beta$).

Comment: Ah yes, I assume you mean this pdf: $g(x;\alpha,\beta) = \beta^{\alpha}\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)} x^{\alpha-1} e^{-\beta x} \quad \text{ for } x \geq 0 \text{ and } \alpha, \beta > 0$? If so, I still can't seem to figure out what $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are since $x = \sigma$ but there is a $\sigma^2$... and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can't be functions of $\sigma$

Answer (score 0):

Look at Arnold Zellner's appendix on distributions in his bayesian textbook. You have an inverted gamma, often the posterior distribution of a standard deviation. The inverse gamma is different, it is the often the posterior distribution of a variance, sigma squared. The distribution of a precision would be a gamma.